# ambiguous option: --o (OptionParser::AmbiguousOption) error received when running Selenium, ruby script

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, watir

I am trying to run the project which is built using Watir, Ruby and Cucumber which was previously working on different version of software/system details.

Current System details which is facing issue :

```
Windows 8
Cucumber version : 2.0.0
gem version : 2.4.6
Ruby version: ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x64-mingw32]
```

the pack was working on below configuration:

```
Windows XP/7
Cucumber 1.3.17
Gem : 2.0.14
Ruby: 2.0.0p481
```

**When I run my script using rake command, I get below mentioned error:**

```
ambiguous option: --o (OptionParser::AmbiguousOption)
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:253:in `parse!'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/configuration.rb:25:in `parse!'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:64:in `block in configuration'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `tap'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:63:in `configuration'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:35:in `execute!'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucum
ber-2.0.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Automation/SeleniumAutomationUsingRuby/Ruby221/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

I tried searching for some answers to this, but looks like no one faced this before. So could you please help me in trying to identifying what has gone wrong

Comment: Unless you are expecting to get an answer from a fortuneteller, please share the content of your `Rakefile`.

Comment: wow, so many differences, different ruby, but most importantly, very different cucumber.   as a first step I might try using the same version of cucumber.  barring that we really need to see the specific line where the error occurs

Comment: This issue got resolved after I updated code to refer --out from --o for generating html report.